# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, raapl, value = c(-0.000180066625137698, : replacement has 524 rows, data has 525

Tags: r

beginner here, learning R. I need help with following: I get an error:

> ```
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, raapl, value = c(-0.000180066625137698,  : 
>  replacement has 524 rows, data has 525
> ```

while trying diff and log function. Here is the code line:

```
# In column 'raapl', save the log returns calculated using rt=ln(Pt/Pt-1)=ln(Pt)-ln(Pt-1)
data$raapl <- diff(log(data$Close), lag = 1)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` returns one fewer values than you give it as input (because it computes the differences between pairwise adjacent values). As a consequence, you cannot assign its result to a column in the same data.frame: all columns must have the same length.

What you *can* do is fill in the missing value, either at the beginning or at the end; e.g.:

```
data$raapl <- c(NA, diff(log(data$Close), lag = 1))
```